# Why does Java and Kotlin show different warnings for deprecated methods?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm wondering why sometimes Java and Kotlin don't show the same warnings for deprecated methods.

For example, in an `Activity`, I can get a color like this in Java:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color);
```

Same code in Kotlin would be this:

```
resources.getColor(R.color.my_color)
```

But if I do that in Java I don't get a warning. If I do it in Kotlin I get the following warning:

> 'getColor(Int): Int is deprecated. Deprecated in Java. Use 'getColor(Int, Theme): Int' instead.

Comment: Ideally both of them should *show* a warning as the method is *actually* deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getColor(int)

Comment: This method is deprecated in both Java and Kotlin with Android M. It also supports setting the theme parameter with Android M to increase support for Material UI I believe. Now, it takes color and theme parameters. If you don't want to use theme, you can pass null for it and it will remove the warning.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar The question is different. Android Studio doesn't display the warning using a java class.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes ! I know it's deprecated and I know why, just wondering why when I use it in a java class I get no warning from Android Studio.